# Filling in a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists:

```
num = ['10', '10', '10', '88', '77', '77', '10']
typ = ['KB', 'BK', 'KB', 'TP', 'HK', 'KH', 'KB']
```

I want to make a dictionary of dictionaries that will look like this:

```
{'10':{'KB':3, 'BK':1}, '88':{'TP':1}, '77':{'HK':1, 'KH':1}}
```

I will have a main dictionary of numbers and for each number I want to count the occurrences of 'typ' that comes with each number.

I tried this:

```
di={}

for i in num:
    if i not in di:
        di[i]={}     
        for x in typ:
            di[i][x]+=1
```

and get this error:

```
KeyError: 'KB'
```

What is the best way to fill in the dictionary for each number in num?

Comment: First, draft your requirement/question properly, you will find your mistake. In additional, this question will be risked voting down.

Comment: You simply need to check that the key exists in your inner dictionary, can't add += 1 to No key...

Comment: @mootmoot - what do you mean "properly"? If they didn't do it "properly", they could probably use a pointer on how to do it. And it looks fine to me. Try not to be negative for no reason, and without constructive feedback.

Comment: IMHO, the best way to avoid cargo cult programming (AKA C&P), is make the question and specification clean.   @eskaev  give the best answer because . i. defaultdict is required. ii. When assign dict within dict, you must assign value to the inner level , that's  .get() come into picture.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short solution using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
num = ['10', '10', '10', '88', '77', '77', '10']
typ = ['KB', 'BK', 'KB', 'TP', 'HK', 'KH', 'KB']

d = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in zip(typ, num):
    d[v][k] = d[v].get(k, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You never checked if `x` was in `di[i]`, so you can't `+=1` since it doesn't already exist.

```
di={}

for i in num:
    if i not in di:
        di[i]={}     
        for x in typ:
            if x not in di[i]:
                di[i][x] = 0
            di[i][x]+=1
```

Since you want a default value of zero, Python can help by using a `defaultdict`:

```
import collections
di = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
for i in num:
    for x in typ:
        di[i][x] += 1
```

And to combine with some other answers, using `zip`:

```
import collections
di = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
for n, t in zip(num, typ):
    di[n][t] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()` with `dict.get()`:

```
di = {}
for n, t in zip(num, typ):
    di[n] = di.get(n, {})
    di[n][t] = di[n].get(t, 0) + 1
```

The problem with yours is that you said `+= 1`.  The first time you do that, `di[i][x]` has not yet been defined.  `di[i][x] += 1` is pretty much a shortcut for `di[i][x] = di[i][x] + 1`, but since you haven't yet defined `di[i][x]`, there is a KeyError.  In mine, however, I use `di[n].get(t, 0)` which means `di[n][t]` if `di[n]` has the key `t`, but 0 otherwise.

Comment: I add my vote because this is alternate answer to eskaev.  Explain the problem of dictionary assignment.

Comment: @mootmoot: I have edited.  Is there anything that could potentially be unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the `collections`  module

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in zip(num, typ):
...     d[item[0]].append(item[1])
... 
>>> {key:Counter(values) for key, values in d.items()}
{'88': Counter({'TP': 1}), '77': Counter({'HK': 1, 'KH': 1}), '10': Counter({'KB': 3, 'BK': 1})}
```

If you feel the need to convert to `dict` then:

```
>>> {key:dict(Counter(values)) for key, values in d.items()}
{'88': {'TP': 1}, '77': {'HK': 1, 'KH': 1}, '10': {'KB': 3, 'BK': 1}}
```

You can also use the `setdefault` method instead of `Counter`

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for item in zip(num, typ):
...     d.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item[1])
... 
>>> d
{'88': ['TP'], '77': ['HK', 'KH'], '10': ['KB', 'BK', 'KB', 'KB']}
>>> {k: dict(Counter(v)) for k, v in d.items()}
{'88': {'TP': 1}, '77': {'HK': 1, 'KH': 1}, '10': {'KB': 3, 'BK': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my shot at it,

```
num = ['10', '10', '10', '88', '77', '77', '10']
typ = ['KB', 'BK', 'KB', 'TP', 'HK', 'KH', 'KB']

result ={}

for x,y in enumerate(num):
    if not y in result.keys():
        result[y] = dict()
    try:
        result[y][typ[x]] += 1
    except KeyError:
        result[y][typ[x]] = 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a `zip`:

```
d ={}

for n,t in zip(num,typ):
    if n not in d:
        d[n] = {t:1}
    else:
        if t not in d[n]:
            d[n][t] = 1
        else:
            d[n][t] += 1
```

output:

```
{'10': {'BK': 1, 'KB': 3}, '77': {'HK': 1, 'KH': 1}, '88': {'TP': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do it:

```
num=['10', '10', '10', '88', '77', '77', '10']
typ=['KB', 'BK', 'KB', 'TP', 'HK', 'KH', 'KB']

di={}

for i in range(len(num)):
    if num[i] not in di:
        di[num[i]]={}     
    if typ[i] not in di[num[i]]:
        di[num[i]][typ[i]] = 1
    else:
        di[num[i]][typ[i]] += 1
```